# Nested stored procedure VS Exec procedures in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure for filling data mart and in this procedure, it calls many other procedures.

In those stored procedures I use temp table with same name. When I execute nested procedure something is wrong. These temp tables somehow stir and distort my data but if I execute these multiple procedures in query as script, that works fine.

I have no clue why it is happening and can you please give me some ideas? What is difference between executing multiple procedures in same query and using other procedure to exec this procedures.

Comment: A Temp Table (`#table`) created by one stored procedure is visible, and alterable, by any stored procedure called by the first stored procedure, but are descoped when the dtor d procedure thst created it finishes.  If you want to treat the table as a variable (and so NOT be in scope by any subsequently called stored procedures) use Table Variables (`@table`), not Temp Tables.

Comment: If the temp table is not intended to be shared between procedures make each name unique eg by prefixing with the procedure name/acronym.